# DIY car not moving in a straight line

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, robotics, encoder, pwm

I'm working on a project, in which I have assembled a 4 wheeled small DIY car, it has 4 DC motors, a raspberry pi 3b+, an L289D H bridge and two optical wheel encoders, one on each wheel on each side.

The problem that I'm currently facing is that the car won't drive in a straight path. I have used PWM to correct it as well but it would still deviate and would not drive straight.

Initially I was just playing around with the PWM values using trial and error, but now I'm using the input from the encoders to modify the PWM values in real time.

Below is the code that I'm using to test the process:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import math
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  #Right encoder
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)   #Left encoder

GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)   #clockwise left
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)   #anticlockwise right
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)   #anticlockwise left
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)   #clockwise right

GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)   #enabler h bridge
GPIO.setup(29, GPIO.OUT)   #enabler h bridge

p=GPIO.PWM(22,100)        #for right wheel
q=GPIO.PWM(29,100)        #for left wheel

stateLast1 = GPIO.input(11)
rotationCount1=0
stateCount1=0

stateLast2 = GPIO.input(7)
rotationCount2=0
stateCount2=0

circ=62.4*math.pi #mm
statesPerRotation=20
distancePerStep= circ/statesPerRotation

p.start(100)
q.start(100)

GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)

distance1 = 0
distance2 = 0
stateCountTotal1=0
stateCountTotal2=0
stateLast1 = 0
stateLast2 = 0

while distance1 <= 300 or distance2 <= 300 :

    stateCurrent1 = GPIO.input(11)
    stateCurrent2 = GPIO.input(7)

    if stateCurrent1 != stateLast1:
        stateLast1 = stateCurrent1
        stateCount1 += 1
        stateCountTotal1 += 1
    
    if stateCount1 == statesPerRotation:
        rotationCount1 += 1
        stateCount1 = 0
    
    
    if stateCurrent2 != stateLast2:
        stateLast2 = stateCurrent2
        stateCount2 += 1
        stateCountTotal2 += 1
    
    if stateCount2 == statesPerRotation:
        rotationCount2 += 1
        stateCount2 = 0    

    distance1 = distancePerStep * stateCountTotal1      #distance travelled by right enc
    distance2 = distancePerStep * stateCountTotal2      #distance travelled by left enc

    if distance1 > distance 2 : 
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(95)        #reduce power of right wheels
            
    if distance2 > distance 1 : 
        q.ChangeDutyCycle(95)        #reduce power of left wheels

GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
GPIO.cleanup()
```

I've messed with the PWM settings in changedutycycle. Upon printing distances 1 & 2 at the end, I either get constant values of either distance 1 or 2, while the other distance would have a difference of about 3cm-10cm.
Only sometimes would I get both distances to be about the same, the least difference between them being less than 1cm, and in only those cases would the car move in a near perfect straight line which is good enough. I don't understand why I'm not getting consistent results.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware problem (how accurate are the sensors and your steering mechanism?) than a software problem.

Comment: The best overall solution to your problem is to use PID controller for each wheel. As for your solution, your adjustments don't really make sense. You reduce DutyCycle to 95, but you never adjust it back. You probably have both side at 95 after a few loops. You should also look if your wheels drift on your surface. Try running your code while the wheels are not touching anything and look at the results. Try also looking at the speed of each wheel and see if there's any inconsistency.

Comment: What I did was that I reduced the value of duty cycle by 5 (by creating a variable) for both if conditions for distance 1 & 2. What happens is that the car would jerk a bit and it would stop immediately giving an error that the dutycycle value is not between 0 to 100. Upon printing the values, I saw that the duty cycle value fell below 0 and to -5 within milliseconds. I think that the processing speed is so high that the initial jerk causes one of the distances to be greater than the other, thus it remains true for all the next iterations until dutycycle falls below 0. How can I solve this?